# Splitting String of Numbers into String[]

Tags: c#, split

Splitting a string of numbers separated by spaces or commas into a string array doesn't seem to work.

Using the code

```
string numStr = "12 13 2 7 8 105 6 5 29 0";
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',' };
string[] numArray = numStr.Split(delimiterChars);
```

I expect numbers to contain "12", "13", "2", "7", "8", "105", "6", "5", "29", "0" but instead numArray[0] = "12 13 2 7 8 105 6 5 29 0"

I've also tried using the following code but it doesn't work either.

```
string[] keywords = Regex.Split(numstr, @"(?<=\d) |, ");
```

Comment: eeeh, no, you *get* an array with 10 values: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nwe7ed.

Comment: Your numbers are delimited by Unicode character `0xC2A0`; whatever this is - it is _not_ a space

Comment: @BillTürstandswithUkraine that is the utf-8 encoding of [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space); in unicode terms, it would be better to say "U+00A0" (rather than `0xC2A0`, which is encoding-specific)

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this because the code *does actually repro*; the problem here is that the markdown processor being used by Stack Overflow is *replacing* the problematic character; if you copy paste from [the *edit* page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74768864/edit): it repros (/cc @PrasadTelkikar)

Comment: the fix here being: either *make sure the input text `numStr` doesn't use nbsp*, or: allow nbsp as a delimiter; for example: `char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '\u00A0' };`

Comment: Your regex has the same problem in that you use the wrong whitespace characters. You can reference the class of whitespace in regex with `\s`: `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(numStr, "\\s")`